# create list using if and else condition

Tags: python, list

```
for tup in totalMean:
    if tup >= 12 and tup <=33:
        print tup(list)
    elif tup >= 49 and tup <=52:
        print tup   
    elif tup >= 58 and tup <=67:
        print tup
    elif tup >= 79 and tup <=98:
        print tup
```

Comment: Please elaborate your question. to provide a better understanding.. also include your source data, expected output and any contextual information that is needed.

Comment: I need to output results into list something like [33,12] [52,51,49] [67,58] [98,91,89,82,79]  so far I am getting output in following format 12
33
49
51
52
58
67
79
82
89
91
98
I am a newbie to programming ..I tried append, zip etc but it did not worked for me. Not to sure how can I achieve it.

Comment: I have a list say totalMean = [98,91,89,82,79,67,58,52,51,49,33,12]

Comment: to clarify, you want your result to be stored into a list A of lists where the inner lists hold the integers in a given range. is that right?

Comment: Yes. If I have a list of number totalMean = [98,91,89,82,79,67,58,52,51,49,33,12] i need to get result in [33,12] or [12,33] but i am getting result 12
33

Comment: I don't know if I am using right approach to achieve the result desired. if there is better way to program this. Please let me know. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are looking for something like this I asume.

```
totalMean = [98,91,89,82,79,67,58,52,51,49,33,12]
list12_33 = []
list49_52 = []
list58_67 = []
list79_98 = []

for tup in totalMean:
    if tup >= 12 and tup <=33:
        list12_33.append(tup)
    elif tup >= 49 and tup <=52:
        list49_52.append(tup)
    elif tup >= 58 and tup <=67:
        list58_67.append(tup)
    elif tup >= 79 and tup <=98:
        list79_98.append(tup)

print [list12_33, list49_52, list58_67, list79_98]
```

the result looks like:

```
[[33, 12], [52, 51, 49], [67, 58], [98, 91, 89, 82, 79]]
```

hope this helped.

Comment: This definitely helped. Thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

Sounds to me like you're trying to sort the values into ranges:

```
totalMean = [33, 12, 52, 51, 49, 67, 58, 98, 91, 89, 82, 79]
buckets = {limits: [] for limits in ((12, 33), (49, 52), (58, 67), (79, 98))}

for tup in totalMean:
    for lo, hi in buckets:
        if lo <= tup <= hi:
            buckets[(lo, hi)].append(tup)
            break

result = [sorted(buckets[limits]) for limits in sorted(buckets)]
print(result)
```

Output:

```
[[12, 33], [49, 51, 52], [58, 67], [79, 82, 89, 91, 98]]
```